# Extra character is gettting added in API URL in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular10

Environment file

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    name: 'local',
    apiUrl: 'https://dev.xyz.com/v1',
};
```

API service

```
login(input: ILogin): Observable<any> {
    Common.showConsoleLog('demoAPIReq', input);
    const url1 = 'https://dev.xyz.com/v1/auth/login'
    const url = `${environment.apiUrl}${consts.LOGIN}`;
    return this.http.post(url, input, { 
        headers: Common.authHeader(), observe: 'response'
    }).pipe(tap (data => Common.showConsoleLog('demoAPIRes', data)),
    catchError(this.handleError('login'))
);
```

Common file

```
static authHeader(): any {
    const httpBearerOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
    };
    return httpBearerOptions.headers;
}
```

Const file

```
export const consts = {
    ROUTE_HOME: 'home',
    ROUTE_LOGIN: 'login',
    ROUTE_REGISTER: 'register',
    ROUTE_DASHBOARD: 'dashboard',
    LOGIN: '​/auth/login',
};
```

If I pass url1 in post api then its working fine , Also `const url3 = environment.apiUrl + '/auth/login';` is also working  but I concate string as in `` const url = `${environment.apiUrl}${consts.LOGIN}`; ``
then its add some weird extra character in url when I checked into network tab as like below [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what `consts.LOGIN` is, but that looks like the problematic area. The "extra characters" you are seeing in the URL is the URL encoded version of `consts.LOGIN`, so you may need to fix that value or make it encode/decode where necessary.

```js
const someVal = "some value with spaces";
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(someVal);
const decoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded);
console.log('encoded', encoded);
console.log('decoded', decoded);
```

I also believe that you want to add a `/` in the URL you're trying to build:

```
const url = `${environment.apiUrl}${consts.LOGIN}`;
```

should probably be:

```
const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/${consts.LOGIN}`;
```

Comment: At least the slashes are not consistent. Either all of the const values should start with a `/` or none (in the latter case you need it when you build the url).